# Rails update button now throwing error :: param is missing or the value is empty: phonecall

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive a table - with params as below

```
def phonecall_params
  params.require(:phonecall).permit(:call_for_id, :call_from_id, :message, :closedcall,:input_by_id ,:company_id )
end
```

I was toggling the callclosed option with

```
button_to 'Close' , phonecall , method: :patch , data: { closedcall: false , phonecall: :phonecall } , class: "btn-primary"
```

but I now get this error ?
param is missing or the value is empty: phonecall

after adding 2 new fields company_id and input_by_id but I cant understand why as Im calling the collection with :phonecall and this is set as the class ? i think

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by operating around it, creating a method then a view in the controller to call the method, the button simply links to the path to call the method